# How do I make my NAS box, which is connected to my desktop directly via ethernet, visible to our home network?

Tags: networking, home-networking, ethernet, nas, crossover-cable

I have a NAS unit that I attached to my Windows desktop via direct ethernet cable. I have it set to use automatic DNS, and it retrieves an IP address from my desktop with no further configuration. I'd like to be able to view this NAS from another computer connected to our home network, if possible. Again, to clarify, the desktop is connected to our home network via Wi-Fi, and the NAS box is connected to the desktop via direct ethernet cable.

What's the relationship between the IP address that my desktop assigns to the NAS and the IP address that our router assigns to my desktop? Short of plugging it into our router, how do I make the NAS visible to the wider network?

Comment: If stuff on the NAS is visible on the desktop, can't you "share" those things with others on the home network using the usual Windows techniques?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd like to be able to get to the administration interface from other machines as well. This requires entering the NAS's IP address.

Comment: If you want the NAS to be visible to browse on your Windows network you will have to install/enable Samba and set your workgroup name in the Global section.
If you just want to be able to connect to it you should be able to do this from other windows machines using its IP address and you really want to give it a static address.

Comment: Why don't you connect the NAS direct to the router?

Comment: Lord Peter, I tried to access the NAS with the IP given to it by my desktop from another machine, but it didn't work. Is there some Windows Firewall stuff I have to do first?

Dave Rook, my router is in another room and I want to keep the NAS close to my desktop, for now.

Comment: Check that all your IP addresses are on the same subnet. Are they all supplied by the same DHCP server? Are your PCs all in the same workgroup?

Comment: What is happening is this:
Your computer is connected to your network (router/switch/etc), and also to the NAS via a different ethernet port (at least this is how it sounds)
You are then able to connect to the NAS from your computer but not from others on the network.

If you want to fix that, and for some reason can't connect the NAS directly to your network, then set it to use an IP in the range of the rest of your network and then bridge the two adapters in windows. Then the NAS will have direct access to the rest of the network via your desktop, although this is not the ideal solution.

Comment: @Archagon - WHY? What possible reason do you have to need an external drive (which the whole point of it is to be visible on a network (hence why it's called NAS)) *near* your computer? Unless it looks really nice, or is the idea coffee table as well I can't see any reason; I'm really interested in why. If it helps, my set up is: 1 router with 4 ports. 1 port goes to 1 NAS. Another port goes to a NAS. 1 port goes to a powerline adapter. And the rest is wireless. This is all stuck away, in a corner of our spare room and it works perfectly. Both NAS are on line to all devices (PC,netbook,phone).

Comment: Really, it's more of a networking exercise for me than anything. I want to understand how all the pieces fit together.